# Transforming Heaps

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, heap

I'm currently stuck on this heap transformation problem and would appreciate any help or insights you can provide.

***Consider the following two (min) heaps, represented using arrays: Heap A: [ , 4, 5, 6, 15, 9, 7, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] Heap B : [ , 3, 8, 5, 15, 9, 6, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 7 ] What minimal sequence of insert and/or removeMin operations on heap A will transform it into heap B ?***

1. HEAP A

[image: HEAP A]

2. HEAP B:

[image: HEAP B]
**So far this is my answer:**

```
removeMin(): This will remove the minimum element from Heap A, which is 4.


Heap A: [ , 5, 6, 15, 9, 7, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] 
insert(7): This will insert the element 7 into Heap A, maintaining the heap property.


Heap A: [ , 5, 6, 15, 9, 7, 7, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] 
removeMin(): This will remove the minimum element from Heap A, which is 5.


Heap A: [ , 6, 7, 15, 9, 7, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] 
insert(6): This will insert the element 6 into Heap A, maintaining the heap property.


Heap A: [ , 6, 7, 15, 9, 7, 6, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] 
removeMin(): This will remove the minimum element from Heap A, which is 6.


Heap A: [ , 7, 7, 15, 9, 7, 6, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] 
insert(5): This will insert the element 5 into Heap A, maintaining the heap property.


Heap A: [ , 7, 7, 15, 9, 5, 6, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] 
removeMin(): This will remove the minimum element from Heap A, which is 5.


Heap A: [ , 7, 7, 15, 9, 5, 6, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] 
insert(3): This will insert the element 3 into Heap A, maintaining the heap property.


Heap A: [ , 7, 7, 15, 9, 3, 6, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 8 ] 
After these operations, Heap A will be the same as Heap B:

Heap A: [ , 3, 8, 5, 15, 9, 6, 20, 16, 25, 14, 12, 11, 7 ]
```

I've given it my best shot, but I'm still struggling to find the optimal sequence of operations for same kind of question, it takes me hours to solve it. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I must have missed your lecture: I can't see how A and B represent min heaps to begin with. In your state sequence, there are multiple consecutive identical states.

Comment: I think I did some mistake somewhere, I'm still uncertain about my answer so I'm posting here seeking for help.

Comment: Also what is the suspicious comma at the beginning of every list? Is the first number missing?

Comment: i just edited my question with image of heap A and B if that helps you

Comment: 0th index is ignored for simplification of Parent-Child Index Calculations. And I reckon that these heaps could be in the middle of being constructed and they haven't gone under Heapify process.

Comment: Just remove the 4 and then insert 3

Comment: oh yeah, that's right! My answer was bad. Do you have any tips to solve these kind of question?

Comment: Well it is clear that A had 4 which is not in B, and A did not have 3 which is in B, so your first try would be to resolve that. To start by inserting 7 is not intuitive: you'd need to explain why you want to insert 7 when there is already a 7 in A, and B has only one 7.

Comment: I believe I attempted this previously but perhaps erred, causing me to overlook the solution and go in circles. I'm dealing with some issues that I think they aren't as simple as a this. Therefore, I'm curious if there are any strategies or advice that could assist me in resolving these matters.